# need the correct code with conditional if in as3

Tags: flash, codeigniter, actionscript-3

hi i am making a game in flash as3 ios devices, but I have a problem with the code:

```
if (e.MOUSE_DOWN right_btn ==) {
```

I said that is not correct MOUSE_DOWN

The game is controlled with buttons,this is a platform game but I'm just doing the movement with the buttons and I have problems. please help

The code complete:

```
var izquierdaPulsada:Boolean = false;
var derechaPulsada:Boolean = false;
var arribaPulsada:Boolean = false;
var abajoPulsada:Boolean = false;

var xScrollSpeed:int = 10;
var yScrollSpeed:int = 10;



abajo_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
arriba_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function keyDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == izquierda_btn){
izquierdaPulsada = true;

} else if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == derecha_btn){
derechaPulsada = true;

} else if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == arriba_btn){
arribaPulsada = true;

} else if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == abajo_btn){
abajoPulsada = true;

}
}


function keyUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == izquierda_btn){
izquierdaPulsada = false;

} else if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == derecha_btn){
derechaPulsada = false;

    } else if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == arriba_btn){
arribaPulsada = false;

} else if(e.MOUSE_DOWN == abajo_btn){
abajoPulsada = false;
}
}


function loop(e:Event):void{
    if(izquierdaPulsada){
        background.x += xScrollSpeed;

    } else if(derechaPulsada){
        background.x -= xScrollSpeed;

    }

    if(arribaPulsada){
        background.y += yScrollSpeed;

    } else if(abajoPulsada){
        background.y -= yScrollSpeed;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `e.MOUSE_DOWN` to `e.target`